# How to install opencv_contrib repository on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, opencv3.0, sift

I want to use the FLANN based matcher for feature matching. For this, the SIFT algorithm is required. In Linux, one can use the 'cmake' and 'make' commands.

But how to install **opencv_contrib** on Windows ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use cmake in windows as well. 
if you're having trouble watch this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vp0AbhXXTrw
I've included the 'face' module for demonstration. You can add 'xfeatures2d' module to use SIFT

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try it :)